# extjs - How to filter grid data except selected value in combo box

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox, combobox

Ext js has in built function for Grid store called filter and which filter grid result with selected value from combobox.

I want reverse of it. It should filter grid data except selected data.

Example: By default, All check box are selected at first. When I uncheck any checkbox than grid should be show data except that selected checkbox.

[Please find screenshot for filter options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aqPd.png)

Following is the code which I have tried but it does filter grid with selected checkbox.

```
var filterArray = [];

filterArray.push({
                   id: 'h2',
                   property: 'vehicle_trafic_light',
                   value: 'Y',     //For Yellow-Ball
                   anyMatch: true,
                   ensitive: false
                 }); 
filterArray.push({
                   id: 'h2',
                   property: 'vehicle_trafic_light',
                   value: 'G',      //For Green-Ball
                   anyMatch: true,
                   ensitive: false
                 });

store.filter(filterArray);
```

Let me know if anyone have any suggestion for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filterFn](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.data.Store.html#cfg-filters) for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can user [filterBy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/Ext.data.Store.html#method-filterBy)

**filterBy** takes a function (lets call is fun) as argument and  function fun is called for each record in store.

```
store.fliterBy(function(record){
        if(condition to include record)
            return true;                    // record will be included
        else
            return false;                   // record will be excluded
});
```

And records are filtered based on return value of fun for that record.

So,

1. If fun return true for record A, then record A will be included in store.
2. If fun returns false for record B , then record B will be excluded.